# Retrieving JSON data from MongoDB with Hebrew values using Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm new to MongoDB - and I'm having this problem when I retrieve a key from my JSON based MongoDB - it cannot parse Hebrew key values and it returns them `blank` when I read them.

I had this problem before when I read and wrote to the JSON file locally, using UTF-8 encoding solved this problem like in this example:

```
with codecs.open('words.json', 'wb', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        json.dump(data, file, ensure_ascii=False)
```

So my question is, is there a way to retrieve MongoDB data using utf-8 encoding?
i'm currently using `find()` to read my data.

like that:

```
for x in mycol.find():
  topic = 'בדיקה'
  print(x[topic])
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the nice guy above me tried - it was indeed my workspace environment that caused the problem for some reason - if you ever face this kind of problem with mongodb, simple try using a clean different work environment and console to see if it fixed the issue.

***use different code editor

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your error. This snippet seems to work for me:

```
import pymongo

mycol = pymongo.MongoClient()['mydatabase']['mycol']

mycol.delete_many({})
mycol.insert_one({'בדיקה': 'בדיקה'})

for x in mycol.find():
    topic = 'בדיקה'
    print(x[topic])
```

prints:

```
בדיקה
```

Comment: hmmmmmmm, i'll try the same code on different environment to see if it solves the problem and will update.

Comment: as i guessed, that was the problem - thank you for checking it with me!